# bigglm - ran out of iterations and failed to converge

Tags: r, bigdata, glm

I have a question. I searched for an answer elsewhere, but couldn't solve my problem. Can someone help me out?

I have a dataset of approximately 1 million records with three variables : N (numeric), X(factor), E(numeric). The variable X has approximately 100 levels. When I tried to run the same code, but replacing X by another covariate Y (who only has 4 levels) it works just fine. Maybe it has something to do with the variable X itself? For example some levels of X only have real low frequency of occurence, while this isn't the case for Y. So is this a problem (because bigglm divides the data in chunks, not each chunk might posses all levels of X)?

My machine has only 2 GB RAM. One of the objectives is to use packages in R, such that when reproducing the code on a larger dataset it still works.

Please if you need more details, ask me and I'll provide them.

**str(data) gives the following :**

```
'data.frame'    :   967821 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ E            : num  0.6694 0.418 0.0546 0.1612 0.071 ...
 $ Y            : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 ...
 $ ??           : Factor w/ 2 levels "??",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ??           : Factor w/ 38 levels "??","??",..: 37 29 11 21 24 23 16 36 19 36 ...
 $ ??           : num  77 43 66 72 96 43 45 78 53 65 ...
 $ ??           : num  7.29 12.42 21.88 5.78 2.62 ...
 $ ??           : Factor w/ 1150 levels "1000","1020",..: 494 1003 456 183 163 1055 881 128 1019 1041 ...
 $ ??           : num  52.5 78 37.7 41.1 64.3 ...
 $ ??           : Factor w/ 31 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 22 11 3 3 11 2 11 11 3 2 ...
 $ ??           : num  34.2 48.9 12.2 19.8 44.3 ...
 $ N            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ??           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ X            : Factor w/ 89 levels "18","19","20",..: 36 61 21 24 47 36 48 67 17 18 ...
```

**My code is the following :**

```
library(ffbase)
library(biglm)
data = as.ffdf(data)
regglm2=bigglm.ffdf(N~X+offset(log(E)),data=data, family=poisson(), maxit=100, chunksize=10000)
```

**The error is the following :**

*Warning message:
In bigglm.function(formula = formula, data = datafun, ...) :
  ran out of iterations and failed to converge*

Comment: Things you can ask yourself. How many factor levels are in X and are there some factor which are related to others that cause convergence issues?

Comment: I updated my post. I also indicated something that maybe causes the problem. However I do not know what bigglm exactly does, so it might have nothing to do with it at all...

Comment: I was able to get convergence by grouping some levels with almost no occurence together and applying my code. So my guess is that levels with very low occurence can cause problems, since bigglm divides the data in chunks. A good question than would be : "what to do if you can't group levels with very low occurence?"

Comment: I think you answered your own question... What you can try out still is take a subset of your data (as in open(data); droplevels(as.data.frame(subset(data, X %in% somelevelswithhighoccurenceandsomewithverylow)))) and run glm on it. See if that converges. If it converges, it is caused by the chunking, otherwise by the generalized linear model updates itself. My guess is that it is the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions, either of which could be considered an answer depending on machine resources:

1) Have you increased the number of iterations in the control-list? `maxit` controls that and defaults to a small number. Try increasing to 25

2) Are you sure you need `bigglm`? Have you tried it with just `glm`? That's not a terribly large object. If you are on a 4GB machine then be sure to start with minimal programs and Windoze stuff (whatever those applets along the lower border of the display are called) in your startup configuration, and don't run R along side other programs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately none of both suggestions worked. I will add some additional information to the original post right away. When I try 1, I still have the same error message, but only after 40 minutes. With regard to question 2, I have a 2GB machine and get the error message "Unable to allocate a vector of size...". Above that, one of the objectives of my research is to use packages such that code is reproducible on larger datasets as well.

Comment: try using an smaller chunksize for the memory problem, try more iterations than 100 for the other problem.

Comment: The OP's comment from Aug 24 '13 at 20:18 indicated that smaller chunk sizes would most likely make the convergence issue more severe.